# Light pattern is flashing intermittently using RVIZ/OpenNI with two Kinects

Tags: ros, kinect, openni

I have two Kinects (each on its own USB card) whose cameras I'm watching in RVIZ through OpenNI, and the structured light pattern of one is flashing intermittently - it's only there for a short flash every two seconds. Obviously, the structured light depth calculations only work if the pattern is always projected when the camera is looking at it.

What causes this, and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I was also having this issue with a single Kinect, for which I discovered the issue, as detailed in my own answer. However, the problem persists when two Kinects are plugged in, with one Kinect flashing and the other functioning normally.

Answer (score 1):

Apparent partial issue was a conflict with the VM running Windows (on my Linux box) attempting to grab the XnSensorServer resource. Running the VM and then the setup specified in the question produced the observed Kinect disfunctionality, whereas running the setup and then opening the VM crashed the XnSensorServer, freezing the Kinect altogether.